# How to reverse-i-search in ksh through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, ksh

I'm currently using PuTTY to connect to some Linux server (`ksh` on RHEL if that matters).

However using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work (only `^R` appears on the screen).
I'm quite surprised that despite all my search I didn't found anything related to this problem.

I'd like to make it work, so here are my questions:

- Is it possible to use reverse-i-search through SSH?
- Do I have to configure/install anything? (either PuTTY or the server).

Comment: Is your problem solved. If not, then please state clearly why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use reverse-i-search through SSH?

Yes. I use it on daily basis through SSH, although not in `ksh`.

> Do I have to configure/install anything?

Your shell is `ksh`. This Linux & Unix SE question applies: [Why can't Korn Shell do ctrl-r?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277789/108618)

From the accepted answer:

> <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> works with `ksh` in `emacs` mode (`ksh -o emacs` or `set -o emacs` within `ksh`), and it was most probably the first shell to support it. Only it's not as interactive as in `zsh` or `bash` or `tcsh`'s `i-search-back` widget.
>
> In `ksh` (both `ksh88` and `ksh93`), you type <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>`text`<kbd>Return</kbd>. And <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to search again with the same text.

Another answer clarifies:

> Now if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, the shell will print `^R`; type your search, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the shell will show you the closest matching history entry. You can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to run it as-is, or edit it.

I have tested it in `ksh` in my Debian, it works.

Comment: So it was because I was using `ksh`, thank you ! I've looked up a little and `history`also displays my last commands, which is pretty useful. However, I can't make "Ctrl+R" "Return" to search again with the same text (it just erases one character from the previous "Ctrl+R" result)